# How to get character positions and assign that vale to variable from string using C#?

Tags: c#

Hi i want to get the position in a string and assign that value to a variable.

Eg

```
 String PrintType= "3in"
 String val ="A4-Format1,A5-Format2,3in-Format3,4in-Format4";
```

Now this is my string. In this i want to find the position of 3in and then i want to find the position of comma(,)  of 3in-Format3. Now after  getting the first and last position i want to assign that value inside of first and last position to one variable.

eg now first postion is 22("3) and the last postion is 3 (3in-Format3(,))is 33.After finding the first and last position  i want to assign that value to one variable

eg

```
  var type = "3in-Format3"
```

Now i find the first postion  by

```
 String PrintType= "3in"
 String val ="A4-Format1,A5-Format2,3in-Format3,4in-Format4";
   String a = val.IndexOf(PrintType);
```

Now i want to find the last position and assign that value between first  and last position to variable. I tired my level best to explain my issue. Please any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this issue.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a regex; but your explanation is super confusing (and I'm not good at regex)

Comment: Not a solution, but idk why you're using `String`, should be `string`.

Comment: You should be able to string together several overloads of [`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) to get there,

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You cant understand

Comment: How about you tell us what you are trying to do instead of how you are trying to do it badly.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i will explain clearly.  one var a = 3in  now i want to get the format of 3inch from that string eg 3inch means i need 3in-Format3 value

Comment: @MatthewWhited                                                                                                    i will explain clearly. var a = 3in now i want to get the format of 3inch from that string eg 3inch means i need 3in-Format3 value

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet did you understand what i am asking

Comment: @snehasusan Nothing to do with what you're asking, you're not setting your data type correctly.

Comment: ok tell me what datatype have to set for that above value

Comment: Maybe it is better to explain what you are trying to do rather than how to do it.  There may be better solutions that finding the index of a comma.

Comment: A `Dictionary` or a `List` would probably be far more appropriate.

Comment: I.. did. It's `string` not `String` (like I said not a solution which is why I did a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string that is a bunch of strings separated by `,`. First, separate the substrings:

`string[] formats = val.Split(',');`.

Now, find the format string that you want:

`string threeInchFormat = formats.First(formatString => formatString.StartsWith("3in"));`

Answer (score 4):

You can write a simple parser in LINQ

```
var formats = "A4-Format1,A5-Format2,3in-Format3,4in-Format4";

var parts = from format in formats.Split(',')
            let formatParts = format.Split('-')
            select new
            {
                Size = formatParts[0],
                Format = formatParts[1],
            };

var format3Size = parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Format == "Format3").Size;
var formatForSize = parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Size == "3in").Format;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you PrintType appears in multiple fields in the line you can do it this way.

```
// multiple fields may have the PrintType
var fields = val
    .Split(',')
    .Where(x => x.IndexOf(PrintType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

// first field in the list will be now in the variable    
var a = fields.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: now its not showing error . It getting the value  now how i get the value and  assign that value in varibale. Eg i need Var a ="3in-Format3"

Answer (score 2):

`IndexOf` can take a start index parameter, which you need to use when finding the comma.  You can use the two indexes to call `Substring`, e.g.

```
var startIdx = val.IndexOf(PrintType);
var endIdx = val.IndexOf(',', startIdx);

var type = val.Substring(startIdx, endIdx - startIdx);
```

However, your real issue is probably how you are storing the data in `val` in the first place (vs. e.g. a dictionary).